# how to properly load a model with a custom layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I'm trying to load a model with a custom layer:

```
siamese_model = load_model(path, custom_objects={'siamese_loss': SIAMESE_LOSS})
```

With a passed dictionary the model should be loaded successfully but the error still popped out:

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: SIAMESE_LOSS
```

The code for the custom layer:

```
class SIAMESE_LOSS(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SIAMESE_LOSS, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def mmd_loss(source_samples, target_samples):
        return mmd(source_samples, target_samples)

    @staticmethod
    def regression_loss(pred, labels):
        return K.mean(mae(pred, labels))

    @staticmethod
    def regression_mse(pred, labels):
        return K.mean(mse(pred, labels))

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        source_labels = inputs[0]
        target_labels = inputs[1]
        source_pred = inputs[2]
        target_pred = inputs[3]
        source_samples = inputs[4]
        target_samples = inputs[5]

        source_loss = self.regression_loss(source_pred, source_labels)
        target_loss = self.regression_loss(target_pred, target_labels)
        mmd_loss = self.mmd_loss(source_samples, target_samples)
        total_loss = source_loss + target_loss + mmd_loss

        source_mse = self.regression_mse(source_pred, source_labels)
        target_mse = self.regression_mse(target_pred, target_labels)

        self.add_loss(total_loss, inputs=True)
        self.add_metric(target_loss, aggregation='mean', name='target_mae')
        self.add_metric(source_loss, aggregation='mean', name='source_mae')
        self.add_metric(mmd_loss, aggregation='mean', name='MMD')
        self.add_metric(target_mse, aggregation='mean', name='target_mse')
        self.add_metric(source_mse, aggregation='mean', name='source_mse')
        return inputs[2], inputs[3]

    def get_config(self, **kwargs):
        super(SIAMESE_LOSS, self).get_config(**kwargs)
```

There's really an important thing that I didn't rewrite `get_config()` method while training the model. Is this the reason for my problem?

Comment: It should be custom_objects={"SIAMESE_LOSS": SIAMESE_LOSS}, as strings are case sensitivve

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried and it actually worked. But it returns some warnings:   WARNING:tensorflow:Output siamese_loss missing from loss dictionary. We assume this was done on purpose. The fit and evaluate APIs will not be expecting any data to be passed to siamese_loss.
WARNING:tensorflow:Output siamese_loss_1 missing from loss dictionary. We assume this was done on purpose. The fit and evaluate APIs will not be expecting any data to be passed to siamese_loss_1.        By the way, what does the key in the dictionary stands for? I thought it were layer.name of the custom layer.